# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'raw-loader'

Tags: ngx-bootstrap, raw-loader

Let me start by saying I realize this isn't specifically an issue with ngx-bootstrap and definitely goes above and beyond the call if anyone ends up being nice enough to help me out, but here's the situation:

A few years ago, we created our own internal fork of ngx-bootstrap that we could modify to fit our needs. It has been generally amazing and the initial work of the ngx-boostrap team is very appreciated. The issue now is in upgrading the dependency to Angular 12, the demo code breaks due to issues with raw-loader...

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'raw-loader`

Here is an example of the code that causes the error:

`code: require('!!raw-loader!./demos/disable-transition/accordion-disable-transition.component.ts').default`

I have found documentation stating the raw-loader isn't compatible with angular-cli 12.2 and greater, but I see you guys have it working above that version. I have been looking through your code, trying to reverse engineer what you did, but can't figure it out. Doesn't anyone have any hints for me?

Thanks a million in advance.